# Using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I try to use Sequelize ORM. Reading documention to this i saw the example

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
title: Sequelize.STRING,
description: Sequelize.TEXT
})

const Task = sequelize.define('task', {
title: Sequelize.STRING,
description: Sequelize.TEXT,
deadline: Sequelize.DATE
})
```

I solved to apply practically in shell node.
I started node in command line

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize')
sequelize.define ...
```

But node said me it is wrong and sequelize dont have the method "define".
SO  i think now where is my error  and im wrong understand documentation

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Just need create new Sequelize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of sequelize:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  database,
  username,
  password,
  {
    host: host,
    logging: false,
    dialect: "mysql",
    port: 3306,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    }
  }
);
```

And after that do define:

```
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
title: Sequelize.STRING,
description: Sequelize.TEXT
})

const Task = sequelize.define('task', {
title: Sequelize.STRING,
description: Sequelize.TEXT,
deadline: Sequelize.DATE
})
```